# R Integer Infinity Value

Tags: r, integer

How can I create a (positive) infinite value in R with type integer.

Just converting `Inf` to integer results in missing values.

```
typeof(Inf)
#> [1] "double"

as.integer(Inf)
#> [1] NA
#> Warning message:
#>   NAs introduced by coercion to integer range 

as.integer(.Machine$integer.max)
#> [1] 2147483647
```

Is this even possible?

From the documentation of `?Inf` it reads (in the See Also section):

> NA, ‘Not Available’ which is not a number as well, however usually used for missing values and applies to many modes, not just numeric and complex.

which might suggest Inf is only available for numeric and complex?!

Comment: Can't be done, int has no inf.

Comment: Why do you need an explicit int? `1L/Inf`, `1L*Inf` and `1L*-Inf` give the right result.

Comment: You could easily create your own S3 class that has an Inf value if you really needed it.

Comment: There is a big gap between 2147483647 (max integer) and Infinity, so it makes sense output NA as an integer, consider `as.integer(.Machine$integer.max)+1L` which will throw a waring `NAs produced by integer overflow` which seems logical as the value cannot be stored in the integer format, so is Not available, but would not be anywhere near infinity.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg there is also a big gap between the maximum numeric value and infinity (an infinitely large gap in fact), yet we have infinity for the numeric class

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. @user2974951 that is what I thought :(
I needed an `int` because the values will be passed to c++ via Rcpp and I dont want to use doubles for this. Due to the usage of Rcpp an S3 class is too much hassle (in my opinion at least). In the end, I resorted to just using `.Machine$integer.max` - "close enough" to infinity :)

Comment: @Allan Cameron, that is true, yet one can wonder if it is legit there is a legit reason there to call a number Infinite due to the fact we cannot store the legit number. At least the definition of Infinity should never be determined by the capacity of storage of the engine you work with. In that sense I am more surpriced that `.Machine$double.xmax * 2` returns `Inf` and not `NA`. As a recap: Infinity is not a number, a number that we cannot store is still a number and not Infinite.

Comment: Makes me wonder why there is not something like `Fin` in R which would be representive for a Finite value but that cannot be stored. If that would be there, that would mean `Fin` value for an integer is still a number but exceeding .Machine$integer.max, while `Fin` on like a number/double would be a Finite number from which we know exceeds .Machine$double.xmax.

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, the max value for integers is .Machine$integer.max, so if you need infinity you will either need to convert it to float or use some substitute for infinity.